# Handling POST and GET requests in Express

Tags: express

First time using express here.

I have the following in my `app.js` file:

```js
const express = require("express");
const mysql = require("mysql");

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "admin",
  password: "password",
  database: "mydb",
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/express"));
app.use(express.urlencoded());  // have also tried with "extended: true" and "extended: false"
app.use(express.json());

// GET
app.get("/getAllUserActivity", (req, res) => {
  const order = req.query.order || "id";
  const page = req.query.page || 0;
  const limit = req.query.limit || 100;

  connection.connect((err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    connection.query(
      "SELECT id, username, counter FROM users ORDER BY ? LIMIT ?,?",
      [order, page, limit],
      (err, results, fields) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.send(results);
      }
    );
  });
});

// POST
app.post("/updateUserActivity", (req, res) => {
  const userId = req.body.userId;
  const username = req.body.username;
  const counter = req.body.counter;

  connection.connect((err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    connection.query(
      "INSERT INTO users (id, username, counter) VALUES (?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE counter = counter + ?",
      [userId, username, counter],
      (err, results, fields) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.send(results);
      }
    );
  });
});
```

My POST requests have the header `"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`.

The issue I am facing is two-fold:

1. The GET request fails every other time. First time it returns the expected data, but the second time I get `Incomplete response received from application` - repeat.
2. I can only get *either* the POST or the GET request to work - depending on how I setup the middleware. How can I have both GET and POST here?

Old php user here, trying to figure out Express. Thanks!

Comment: Please show the real code in your request handlers so we can see what's actually happening.

Comment: @jfriend00 alrighty - added.

Comment: Replace all `if (err) throw err;` with sending an actual error response back to the client.  You MUST always send some form of response to every incoming request.

Comment: I don't know your database, but are you supposed to be released the connection after you're done?

Comment: @jfriend00 Indeed, that might be the issue for #1 above... thanks. But what about #2? That's where I've been stuck on for a few hours now...

Comment: The GET request shouldn't have anything to do with your middleware because the middleware shouldn't be involved in serving the GET request at all, so your description of there being a relationship between the two is confusing and makes me think maybe there's some other code involved than what you show here or you're confused about when the GET request works and what makes it stop working.  If you can show the code for when the GET request works and then show the exact code for when it doesn't, we could better understand.

Comment: @jfriend00 I went over to using connection pools instead for mysql and that solved #1 and I think #2 too. I'll update otherwise. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace all `if (err) throw err;` with sending an actual error response back to the client. You MUST always send some form of response to every incoming request.   It is a shame that many pieces of demo code show that `if (err) throw err;` because inside an asynchronous callback, that is pretty much never the correct code.

Then (though I don't know the specific details of your database) you will need to release/close your database connections after using them so they do not leak.  Or, you can use a pooled set of connections where they are automatically returned to the pool after doing a query.

Comment: Yeah the demo code was quite misleading - you'd think you could take those for granted... thanks for the help!